# Plotting csv file

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am trying to plot some data derived from a csv file but nothing shows up on the r display
window; however, there is no error

Any ideas?

My code:

```
tools <- read.csv (file="tools.csv", header=TRUE)
stones <- read.csv (file="stones.csv", header=TRUE)
coordinates(stones) <- ~stones.POINT_X+stones.POINT_Y
coordinates(tools) <- ~tools.POINT_X+tools.POINT_Y
plot(stones,add=TRUE)
plot(tools,add=TRUE)
```

Comment: We need to know what your data looks like. Please share some by typing `dput(head(tools, 10))` and `dput(head(stones, 10))`   and then pasting the results into your question.

Comment: My data is a csv table from ArcGIS which contains points, fields with attributes (eg. length, width) and x,y coordinates

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible dataset included in your question. One way of doing that is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to do this here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg